# Can't Find Custom Module — ExpressJS + Executed Module

Tags: node.js, express, module

I have an expressJS app with the following structure:

```
app.js (<= require statement here)
tools
└modules
 └tool_A.js
node_modules (dir)
```

I'm trying to include & execute tool_A.js, like so:

```
require('./tools/modules/tool_A.js')();
```

However, it cannot find it.

I've read some of the other answers for similar questions and those solutions did not work for me. Most of them stated that the path is relative to the file that makes the require statement, hence the above, or relative to the node_modules folder, which I also tried and did not work.

I also tried absolute path and that did not work.

Not sure if something will be different because I'm using ExpressJS?

The module file is basic, and I would expect a different error message if it's malformed.

Comment: I'd try some debugging to see what the current path actually is, and try to verify if the file really does exist where you think it does.  Look for what is different during run time from during design time.

Comment: @theGleep - I'm not sure how I would get the current path during run time, can you elaborate?

Comment: I think __currentdir will give it to you.  And you can try "fs.stat" to see if the file exists, and path.resolve() to check what the variable really is doing.

Comment: Could you post the actual error message? Also worth checking the file permissions.